# change date format in pandas

Tags: python, date, pandas, lambda

I had the below csv data

```
country,sale,date,trans_factor
India,403171,12/01/2012,1
Bhutan,394096,12/01/2012,2
Nepal,super,12/01/2012,3
madhya,355883,12/01/2012,4
sudan,man,12/01/2012,5

csv_data = pandas.read_csv(csv_file_data, skiprows=[0], names=original_csv_header, parse_dates=True, infer_datetime_format=True)

print csv_data

  country    sale        date  trans_factor
0   India  403171  12/01/2012             1
1  Bhutan  394096  12/01/2012             2
2   Nepal   super  12/01/2012             3
3  madhya  355883  12/01/2012             4
4   sudan     man  12/01/2012             5
```

Even after adding `parse_dates=True` the above code doesn't changed the values from `12/01/2012` to `2012-01-12`, and i don't know why

I want to format the date column in the format `'%d/%m/%Y'` and so i attempted with the below code

```
dates = {
        'dd/mm/yy': "%d/%m/%Y",
        'mm/dd/yy': "%m/%d/%Y",
    }

def return_date_fromat(d, date_format):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(d, date_format)


csv_data["date"] = csv_data["date"].apply(lambda d: return_date_fromat(d, dates['dd/mm/yy']))
```

basically  i am using another function for lambda as `return_date_fromat` because when i used like below

```
csv_data["date"] = csv_data["date"].apply(lambda d: datetime.datetime.strptime(d, dates['dd/mm/yy'])
```

i am getting `*** NameError: global name 'dates' is not defined` and hence i am using a function `return_date_fromat` for lambda

So finally how to format the date ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need change parameter `parse_dates` to `[2]`, because `True` means parse `DatetimeIndex` see [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#datetime-handling):

> parse_dates
>   : boolean or list of ints or names or list of lists or dict, default False.
>
> If True -> try parsing the index.
>   If [1, 2, 3] -> try parsing columns 1, 2, 3 each as a separate date column.
>   If [[1, 3]] -> combine columns 1 and 3 and parse as a single date column.
>   If {'foo' : [1, 3]} -> parse columns 1, 3 as date and call result ‘foo’. A fast-path exists for iso8601-formatted dates.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""country,sale,date,trans_factor
India,403171,12/01/2012,1
Bhutan,394096,12/01/2012,2
Nepal,super,12/01/2012,3
madhya,355883,12/01/2012,4
sudan,man,12/01/2012,5"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), parse_dates=[2])
#df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), parse_dates=['date'])

print (df)
  country    sale       date  trans_factor
0   India  403171 2012-12-01             1
1  Bhutan  394096 2012-12-01             2
2   Nepal   super 2012-12-01             3
3  madhya  355883 2012-12-01             4
4   sudan     man 2012-12-01             5

print (df.dtypes)
country                 object
sale                    object
date            datetime64[ns]
trans_factor             int64
dtype: object
```

EDIT:

If need custom parser add parameter `date_parser`:

```
parser = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y')
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), parse_dates=[2], date_parser=parser)
print (df)
  country    sale       date  trans_factor
0   India  403171 2012-01-12             1
1  Bhutan  394096 2012-01-12             2
2   Nepal   super 2012-01-12             3
3  madhya  355883 2012-01-12             4
4   sudan     man 2012-01-12             5
```

But works also `dayfirst=True`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), parse_dates=[2], dayfirst=True)
print (df)
  country    sale       date  trans_factor
0   India  403171 2012-01-12             1
1  Bhutan  394096 2012-01-12             2
2   Nepal   super 2012-01-12             3
3  madhya  355883 2012-01-12             4
4   sudan     man 2012-01-12             5
```

Comment: basically i am getting the order of date column dynamically or randomly and so i can't hard core it with `parse_dates=[2]`, so is there anyway to change it to `%d/%m/%Y` once after csv was read ?

Comment: Is possible parse by name of column like `df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), parse_dates=['date'])` ?

Comment: Nope, like i said in the previous post, i had this code `csv_data[foreign_key.table_column_name] = csv_data[foreign_key.table_column_name].apply(
                lambda d: return_date_fromat(d, dates[foreign_key.date_format]))` which i am getting dynamically and so i need to change the format inside the method `return_date_fromat` itself, if you don't mind was that possible ?

Comment: There is only one solution, but it is a bit dangerous - `df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), parse_dates=[0,1,2,3])` - If some integer values are similar as `dates`, it will be parse wrong. :(

Comment: It values like `20120101` or `2000` will be parsed to daetimes wrongly :(

Comment: ok what if i know the position and how to change the format now ? i will try to alter my code based on it

Comment: So you can use `parse_dates=[2]`, is it possible?

Comment: yes, i will try to make that possible from my side, by making some code changes, please let me how to format the date to `%d/%m/%Y`

Comment: You can add parameter `dayfirst=True`

Comment: oh, i din't understood that can you please alter your code on how to use it to get the format as `%d/%m/%Y`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133992/discussion-between-shiva-krishna-and-jezrael).